# Active Directory / Exchange General Tab

Tags: active-directory, exchange

I would like to know how to programatically change the Forwarding address under Delivery Options to None.

Every time I try to set altRecipient to "" there is a constraint error.

How do I remove the forward to user or set the forwarding address to None.

```
testEntry.InvokeSet("deliverAndRedirect", false); // OK
testEntry.InvokeSet("altRecipient", ""); // error
```

Also on the Send on Behalf, how can you remove all the users in the grant list.

Answer (score 1):

You should try clearing the property rather than setting it to "". I'm not much of a C# programmer but you can probably do (or some such):

```
testEntry.Invoke("PutEx", New Object() { ADS_PROPERTY_CLEAR, altRecipient, 0 })
```

The key is that setting the value to "" is different than clearing it.